# Is it possible that network administrators know that I am using 160 WIFI program on my laptop to access to internet

Tags: security, networking

I am using office internet connection through my laptop. I decided to extend the internet to my phone so I install 160 WIFI program ( Wi-Fi hotspot ) in my laptop then I got wireless internet connection , my question is that is it possible network administrators know that I am using that program or identify the extra wireless on their network. how about the devices connected to that new wireless they will be appeared on their log system as extra devices connected to local area network

Comment: Is the connection to your laptop (from your administrators) wireless?

Comment: no it is not , it is a wired cable from my office

Answer (score 0):

> it possible network administrators know that I am using that program

Depends on that program. If that program broadcasts though it's wifi hotspot SSID, BSSID or anything else something that can identify it, then yes.

> or identify the extra wireless on their network

They can see your network if they monitor the wireless spectrum around where you are

> how about the devices connected to that new wireless they will be appeared on their log system as extra devices connected to local area network

No it will most likely not, as your computer will act as a DHCP/NAT server in the hotspot network. The traffic from the phone will be disguised as traffic from your computer. Traffic analysis will however likely be able to detect the precense of NATing and two connected devices, depending on the type of analysis, how long you leave the phone connect, how much you use it, if the traffic is encrypted and much more.

If you want to be undiscovered, you are not doing a great job. If someone wants to discover what you are doing, they will. If no one really cares then they probably will not.

Comment: so it is not possible from their office systems to identify my new wireless or new devices connecting to new wireless

Comment: Yes they can detect your wireless hotspot. Yes they can detect devices you connect to them, given they stay connected for a while and they use the tools needed to discover the devices. But yes it is possible.